# Localization issue. Codestyling localization, incompatible theme

Tags: themes, multi-language, compatibility

(I modified the question.  i .e. I added hyperlink)

My website uses Jobroller theme.

The problem is that it is not compatible with WPML

I am translating themes using codestyling localization
[Link to the code. It is compressed][1]
Could you give me some instructions on what I need to do from here?

Jobroller does not seem to be compatible with codestyling localization.

If I am using an incompatible them, is there a way to achieve compatibility?

( I have added some of the source codes)

[1]: Code http://cafeattach.naver.net/a732bb081c2c2d9db35c320338dca1da782ad1f4/20130527_261_cafefile/24495556_1369658452761_pDfySc_zip/sample_source.zip?type=attachment

Comment: Please add a link to the theme code.

Comment: It's called the Jobroller. I got it some time ago

http://demos.appthemes.com/?theme=jobroller

Comment: That’s not the code, it is the rendered output. There is no answer possible without seeing how the code loads and uses the language.

Comment: Jobroller is 'open source' but not free. I know this sounds strange but I am not too sure how else to put it. I don't think I can just upload the codes.

Comment: Then ask the theme support.

Comment: I posted it with link anyway. I think this much is okay
Thank you.

Comment: I don’t see `load_theme_textdomain()` in those files, and the text domain is used as a constant, not as a string. This is wrong. CSL can handle constants, but without a loaded language file there is no translation possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have generated mo files as in the manual but didn't do anything more. In general how should i change the codes?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t seen all files in your attachment, some directories are not included, so this is just a guess:

1. Create a directory `languages` in the theme for the language files.
2. Add the following to the `style.css` header below `License URI`:

   ```
    Textdomain:  jobroller
    Domain Path: /languages
   ```
3. In `functions.php` add:

   ```
   add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'jobroller_load_language' );

   function jobroller_load_language()
   {
       load_theme_textdomain( 
           'jobroller', 
           get_template_directory() . '/languages' 
       );
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work, it must be the problem with the theme. Jobroller is not compatible with WPML either and a bridge hasn't been published yet. 
Thank you so much anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you’re interested in a tool to easily translate WordPress themes, have a look at the online localization platform https://poeditor.com/ It’s even got a plug-in you can use with it to integrate its API to your WordPress so that you save more time with the file management process. You can find it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/poeditor/